# Sort by index an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Look at the code below:

```js
    var exemples =  [
            {
                'name'     : 'd',
                'index'    : 3
            },
            {
                'name'     : 'c',
                'index'     : 2
            },
            {
                'name'     : 'a',
                'index'    : 0
            },
            {
                'name'     : 'b',
                'index'    : 1
            }
        ];

      const list = exemples.map((exemple, index, array) => exemple.name)

      console.log(list)
```

it gives me that array:

```
["d", "c", "a", "b"]
```

I would like to respect the index and get a result like that:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

Sounds like a basic question but I need your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort the list first, by a custom sort function which will compare the indices, and then map.

```js
    var exemples =  [
            {
                'name'     : 'd',
                'index'    : 3
            },
            {
                'name'     : 'c',
                'index'     : 2
            },
            {
                'name'     : 'a',
                'index'    : 0
            },
            {
                'name'     : 'b',
                'index'    : 1
            }
        ];

      const list = exemples.sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index).map((exemple, index, array) => exemple.name)

      console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to sort and filter.
Use `Array#reduce`.
In just one iteration you can get the sorted elements. This is more efficient than first sorting and then filtering. This would give you O(n) solution. See below as an example.

```js
var exemples = [{
    'name': 'd',
    'index': 3
  },
  {
    'name': 'c',
    'index': 2
  },
  {
    'name': 'a',
    'index': 0
  },
  {
    'name': 'b',
    'index': 1
  }
];

var ans = exemples.reduce(function (r,v) {
  r[v.index] = v.name;
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array before you map it.
Here is an example:

```js
var exemples =  [{'name'     : 'd','index'    : 3},{'name'     : 'c','index'     : 2},{'name'     : 'a','index'    : 0},{'name'     : 'b','index'    : 1}];

const list = exemples.sort((v1, v2) => v1.index - v2.index).map((v) => v.name);
console.log(list)
```